# Dynamically changing React component tag

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

I'm creating a Landing page for a project and want to reduce my code by making a helper function to display my four different paper components. Everything seems to be working correctly except for displaying my Icon components that are within the papers.

When I console log Icon it is the correct text, yet the component doesn't appear on the page and I receive these two warnings for each component tag:

```
"Warning: The tag <CardTravelIcon> is unrecognized in this browser. If you 
meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter."
```

and

```
"Warning: <CardTravelIcon /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase 
HTML tags in React."
```

If I just hard code in CardTravelIcon or any of the other 3 component names in that exact format instead of using Icon from my map function, everything works as expected. Below is the code for my helper function:

```
class Landing extends Component {
  renderPapers() {
    const classes = this.props.classes;
    return _.map(infoPapers, ({ description, Icon }) => {
      return (
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} key={Icon}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <Icon className={classes.paperIcons} />
            {description}
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      );
    });
  }
```

I'm at a loss and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Will you please post the output of this.props.classes ?

Comment: I'm using material UI for my website design and they use this.props.classes as ways to customize styling

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pass a component as a variable, right?

Let's say you have this minimal `CardTravelIcon` component:

```
const CardTravelIcon = ( props ) => (
    <div className={ props.className }>Card Travel Icon</div>
);
```

And `infoPapers` data like this (`Icon` is a reference to the component):

```
const infoPapers = [
{
    description: "Paper 1 description",
    Icon : CardTravelIcon
}];
```

You didn't show us the `infoPapers` data, but I suspect you're trying to pass a string as the component, e.g. `{ Icon : "<CardTravelIcon />" }` and expect it to work like setting innerHTML (rendering HTML from a string). This is not the case in React, the JSX code needs to be transpiled into calls to `React.CreateElement` first, and it isn't done by parsing strings.

If you pass references to components everything should be rendered just fine with the following render method (note: removed lodash in favor of native map method, for clarity):

```
class Landing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return infoPapers.map(({ description, Icon }, idx) => {
      return (
        <div key={ idx }>
            <Icon />
            {description}
          </div>
      );
    });
  }
};
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/svygw338/